# Select data from 2 tables inside array in API Rest

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm creating Restful API in Codeigniter, and have 2 tables that save data from table `orders`. The table `Orders` have basic information columns `id`, `customer`, `status` and `observation`. And `Orders_products` return information about products in a order, this table have a column named `orders_id`(have relationship), `size`, `qty`, `price` and `subtotal`.

It's possible call this values from 2 table in one requisition?

Example what i expect: Inside Items array is `Orders_products` table.

```
{
    "customer_id": 14,
    "status": "2",
    "items": [
        {
            "size": "S",
            "qty": 10,
            "price": 10.50,
            "subprice": 100.50, // qty * price

        },
        {
            "size": "M",
            "qty": 2,
            "price": 10.50,
            "subprice": 21.00, // qty * price

        }]
    "observation": nothing,
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This
use json_decode(items_json) from the loop

```
$this->db->select("t1.id, t1.customer, t1.status,t1.observation,CONCAT('[',t2.json_data,']') items_json");
$this->db->from("Orders t1");
$this->db->join("(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{\"size\":\"',size,'\",\"qty\":','\"',qty,'\",\"price\":','\"',price,'\",\"subprice\":','\"',subprice,'\"}')) AS json_data,order_id
FROM Orders_products group by order_id) t2","t1.id=t2.order_id","left");
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```